Why does groupby with dropna=False prevent a subsequent MultiIndex.dropna() to work?
My understanding is MultiIndex.dropna() removes index entries for which at least one level is NaN, there are no conditions. However it seems if a previous groupby was used with dropna=False, it's no longer possible to use MultiIndex.dropna().

What are the reasons for the different behavior?
How to drop the NaN entries after using groupby?

(I'm aware the NaN groups would be dropped by groupby without the dropna parameter, but I'm looking for a solution working in the case the parameter has been used at some point earlier).

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {(8.0, 8.0): {'A': -1.10, 'B': -1.0},
     (7.0, 8.0): {'A': -0.10, 'B': 0.1},
     (5.0, 8.0): {'A': 1.15, 'B': -1.2},
     (7.0, 7.0): {'A': 1.10, 'B': 1.6},
     (7.0, np.NaN): {'A': 0.70, 'B': -0.7},
     (8.0, np.NaN): {'A': -1.00, 'B': 0.9},
     (np.NaN, 5.0): {'A': -2.20, 'B': 1.1}}

# This works as expected
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(d.keys(), names=['L1', 'L2'])
df = pd.DataFrame(d.values(), index=index)
print(df.index.dropna())

# This doesn't work as expected
df = df.groupby(['L1', 'L2'], dropna=False).mean()
print(df.index.dropna())


MultiIndex([(8.0, 8.0),
            (7.0, 8.0),
            (5.0, 8.0),
            (7.0, 7.0)],
           names=['L1', 'L2'])

MultiIndex([(5.0, 8.0),
            (7.0, 7.0),
            (7.0, 8.0),
            (7.0, nan),
            (8.0, 8.0),
            (8.0, nan),
            (nan, 5.0)],
           names=['L1', 'L2'])


Looking at the sources of pd.MultiIndex.dropna() reveals that there are codes for each value of index.
Pandas expects code value -1 for NaN, which apparently is not the case when doing .groupby() (a bug?).
You can avoid this issue by reconstructing the index and then drop NaN values, e.g.:
df = df.groupby(["L1", "L2"], dropna=False).mean()

# reconstruct the index (this will assign code -1 to NaN):
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index.to_list(), names=df.index.names)

print(df.index.dropna())

Prints:
MultiIndex([(5.0, 8.0),
            (7.0, 7.0),
            (7.0, 8.0),
            (8.0, 8.0)],
           names=['L1', 'L2'])


Very nice catch! Definitely a bug. Just adding that you don't have to reconstruct the entire index. You can reset the codes with pd.MultiIndex.set_codes. I.e., pass the current codes and default verify_integrity=True will reset -1 for NaN. So: df.index.set_codes(df.index.codes).dropna().

@ouroboros1 please make your comment an answer, I'll upvote it. Probably this is more efficient approach than reconstructing the index.

Done. Added a pipe alternative as well

As noted in the answer by @AndrejKesely, pd.MultiIndex.dropna filters out NaN values by dropping the value -1 in df.index.codes.
During df.groupby, it would appear that the codes are being rebuilt without taking into account that NaN should be marked as -1.
df = pd.DataFrame(d.values(), index=index)

print(df.index.codes)
[[2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, -1], [2, 2, 2, 1, -1, -1, 0]] # -1 values mark `NaN` locations

# compare:
df = df.groupby(['L1', 'L2'], dropna=False).mean()

print(df.index.codes)
[[0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3], [2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 0]] # -1 values have become 3!

We can restore the codes with pd.MultiIndex.set_codes, passing the current index. Make sure not to adjust default verify_integrity=True.
df = df.groupby(['L1', 'L2'], dropna=False).mean()
df.index.set_codes(df.index.codes).dropna()

MultiIndex([(5.0, 8.0),
            (7.0, 7.0),
            (7.0, 8.0),
            (8.0, 8.0)],
           names=['L1', 'L2'])

Alternatively, you could also use df.pipe and apply df.set_index, so that the df is immediately 'clean'.
df = (df.groupby(['L1', 'L2'], dropna=False).mean()
      .pipe(lambda x: x.set_index(x.index))
      )

df.index.dropna()

MultiIndex([(5.0, 8.0),
            (7.0, 7.0),
            (7.0, 8.0),
            (8.0, 8.0)],
           names=['L1', 'L2'])

